# linear independence of symmetric tensors

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, tensor-rank, tensor-decomposition

I am reading a paper that incidentally uses a bit of theory of symmetric tensor spaces. I came across the following claim:

If we're given linearly independent vectors 
$x_1, \ldots, x_n \in  \mathbb{R}^n$, then the tensors from the following set

$\{H_T = \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n-t}} \prod_{i \notin T} x_{T(\sigma(i))}:T \subset \{1,\ldots,n \}, |T|=t \}$

are linearly independent.

By $T(i)$ i mean the i-th element of the set $\{1, \ldots,n \} \; \backslash\; T$, and the product sign denotes tensor product.

I'm not really fluent in tensor algebras and when I tried proving it directly, expressing each $x_i$ in terms of standard basis, I drowned in the summing indices. 
Any help regarding a proof of this claim would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant of the $H_T$'s is a power of the determinant of the $x_i$'s, possibly times a nonzero numerical constant.
See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40077/determinant-and-symmetric-power
where this is discussed.